# Java Gui return item

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textfield

I am wanting to get a return from a gui instance 
The code i run to create the GUI:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChatPopup());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

My GUI (ChatPopUp code is as follows:

```
public class ChatPopup extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private JButton cancelButton;
private JTextField textFieldchatRoomName;
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JButton okButton;

public ChatPopup() {
    super();

    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(294, 85));
        {
            jLabel1 = new JLabel();
            this.add(jLabel1);
            jLabel1.setText("Please enter the new chat room name:");
        }
        {
            textFieldchatRoomName = new JTextField();
            this.add(textFieldchatRoomName);
            textFieldchatRoomName.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(263, 22));
        }
        {
            cancelButton = new JButton();
            this.add(cancelButton);
            cancelButton.setText("Cancel");
            cancelButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(84, 22));
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Cancel PRESSED");
                }
            });
        }
        {
            okButton = new JButton();
            this.add(okButton);
            okButton.setText("Ok");
            okButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 22));
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("OK PRESSED");
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

This is a pretty simple GUI which has a text field and 2 buttons one "Ok" one "Chancel".
When i click "Ok" i want the textField value to be sent to the class where the GUI instance is originally run.

Any ideas how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

The `JPanel` you posted should be added to a modal `JDialog` content pane. In the same class, you can provide some methods to return the values the user entered into the text fields.

In the original window, you open the dialog.

```
SomeDialog dialog = new SomeDialog(parent);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

The code after `setVisible()` will only be executed after the modal dialog is closed. At this point you can call the methods I mentioned above for getting the text field values.